# How to get attached mail in mail?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph. Right now I can read attachment by

```
GET /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments
```

But if someone attach a mail in a mail and send to me by using Outlook's **Attachment** feature.

[image]

Then there is no `contentBytes` field returned. So how to get attached mail in mail?

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
            "id": "{attachmentId}",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-02-06T09:08:02Z",
            "name": "Hi",
            "contentType": "message/rfc822",
            "size": 5341,
            "isInline": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$expand` to expand the attachment:

```
GET /me/messages/{id}/attachments/{attach-id}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemAttachment/item
```

Comment: Hi Jason, any doc link? I know `expand`, but at that I don't know I should use `microsoft.graph.itemAttachment/item`. Thanks

Comment: No, not explicit. `microsoft.graph.itemAttachment` is the type that you need to cast the attachment to, and that type has an `item` property that you need. Looking at the docs for itemAttachment (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/itemattachment) they look like they are missing this info.