# What permissions do I need to get a message from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I'm retrieving Outlook email attachments using [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)
and noticed that some emails have a `.eml` attachments. When I get the email attachment by calling `/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}/attachments'` I noticed that the response doesn't contain `contentBytes` key. 
for example:

```
[
  {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
    "id": "AAMkADlkMmfGrEBKuveYeL8nxW0=",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-02T17:12:04Z",
    "name": "single.eml",
    "contentType": "message/rfc822",
    "size": 23811,
    "isInline": false
  }
]
```

Non .eml attachments do contain the `contentBytes`.

So i'm trying this endpoint `me/messages/<Message-Id>/$value` which I got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62193048/2609521)

```
$cid = (new Graph())->setAccessToken($accessToken)
    ->createCollectionRequest("GET",
        '/users/' . $userId . 'messages/' . $outlook_email->getId() . '/$value')
    ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message::class)
    ->execute();
```

but I get this error

```
Client error: `GET https:\/\/graph.microsoft.com\/v1.0\/users\/636cb59d65489cmessages\/AAMkADlkMmIwZ_50gsmT9V9pNAAA=\/$value` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n{\"error\":{\"code\":\"Authorization_RequestDenied\",\"message\":\"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2023-08-02T22:16:55\",\"request-id\":\"d3bcdef3-2c0d08121b5f\",\"client-request-id\":\"d3bcdef308121b5f\"}}}\n
```

I've search through Microsofts [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions) but I can't figure out which permission to set so I can execute that call.

Which permission do I need? Or is there a different way for me to get the `.eml` attachment content?

Answer (score 0):

To get the attached message you have to use

```
/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}/$value'
```

this is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If you can get file attachments on other messages then your permissions should be okay. The exception maybe if you only had Mail.ReadBasic permissions but Mail.Read either delegate or application should be okay. But if you where trying to use the MessageId from the attachment in me/messages//$value that would give you an error.

Comment: I got an error `......L8nxW0=\/$value' resulted in a '400 Bad Request' response:\n{\"error\":{\"code\":\"UnknownError\",\"message\":\"<!DOCTYPE html>......`. This is a screenshot of the html in the message https://ibb.co/271SG9Z

Comment: Try the same request in the Graph Explorer it sounds like you code isn't sending the request through as expected you can use something like fiddler or the Graph developer proxy to view the request and response https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/introducing-the-microsoft-graph-developer-proxy-community-preview/

Comment: I fixed the issue I was missing a `/` before messages but i'm still not seeing a response. When I call `/users/{user_id}/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}/$value` I get an empty object. If I remove `$value` I get an object with these being some of the values `"contentType":"message\/rfc822","size":81068,"isInline":false`

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue I was able to solve it by following this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48648158/2609521